# What is the term for variable auto transformers that are computer controlled?

Tags: transformer, ac

I want to test when some devices consider a voltage to be unfit, so I need to sweep a rather wide range of AC voltages to determine the tripping point. Currently, we have an employee twist the knob of a variable autotransformer by hand.

Is there a product that I can control electrically (I2C, SPI, 4-20,0-10,Modbus,etc.) to produce variable AC voltages?

Comment: Consider a [variable AC power supply](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=variable+AC+power+supply&t=opera&ia=web).  You'll get a lot of hits for DC supplies, but AC supplies are also available, some of which can be automated.

Comment: On top of straight up inverter based variable AC power supplies like @rdtsc mentioned, the poor man’s version of it is a motorized variac.

Comment: I want to to say "auto auto-trasformer"  but I know that's wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@winny has given you the generic name of a product that can do this in an automated fashion.

Maybe also consider simply switching taps on a transformer or buck-boost transformer(s) with mechanical relays if all you need is a few discrete AC voltages (and if your input voltage is stable enough). For example, if your input voltage is nominal 120VAC and you want to simulate 85VAC you could buck the input voltage with a 35VAC transformer.

The big-budget elegant solution is to procure an electronic adjustable AC source like [this](https://www.chromausa.com/pdf/61509%20Programmable%20AC%20Power%20052023.pdf) (no endorsement to this particular product implied, just an example):

[image]

Comment: Uninterruptible power supplies with "automatic voltage regulation" generally use the "just switch taps with a relay" solution. Cheap and cheerful, as they say.

Comment: Thank you. I think that this is all the info I need!

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a product that I can control electrically (I2C, SPI, 4-20,0-10,Modbus,etc.) to produce variable AC voltages?

An RC servo will convert a PWM signal into an angle of rotation, just bolt a large-enough one to the variac shaft.